# How to limit item text length in QListWidgetItem?

Tags: qt, user-interface, qlistwidget

I am developing an application which shows files in certain directory.
Everything is good, except item text.

I use the following code to initialize QListWidget which shows icon contains filename and preview:

```
FlatFSPage::FlatFSPage(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent) {
    QVBoxLayout *layout=new QVBoxLayout;

    m_title=new QLabel;
    m_list=new QListWidget;
    layout->addWidget(m_title);
    layout->addWidget(m_list);
    setLayout(layout);

    m_list->setGridSize(QSize(100, 100));
    m_list->setMovement(QListView::Static);
    m_list->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    m_list->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    m_list->setAttribute(Qt::WA_MacShowFocusRect, false);
    m_list->setViewMode(QListView::IconMode);
    m_list->setIconSize(QSize(64, 64));
    m_list->setResizeMode(QListView::Adjust);
    m_list->setUniformItemSizes(true);

}
```

and use

```
void FlatFSItem::onAddFSItem(QString prefix, QString name) {
    FlatFSPage *page=qobject_cast<FlatFSPage *>(listWidget()->itemWidget(this));
    QListWidget *list=page->m_list;
    QListWidgetItem *item=new QListWidgetItem(list);

    switch(m_type) {
        case ImageFile: {
            item->setIcon(QIcon(":/images/cloud.png"));
            //Use dummy icon first.
            //onUpdateIcon will replace the icon with real preview.

            DelayImageLoader *dli=new DelayImageLoader(this, item, QString("%1/%2").arg(prefix).arg(name));

            QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(dli);
            break;
        }

        default:
            item->setIcon(QIcon(":/images/cloud.png"));
    }

    item->setText(name);
    item->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);

    int newHeight=list->visualItemRect(item).bottom();
    QSize oldSize=sizeHint(), newSize=QSize(oldSize.width(), newHeight+60);
    QSize satSize;

    setSizeHint(newSize);
    satSize=sizeHint();
}
```

to append item to the list control.
To prevent preview-making process from blocking UI, I use thread pool to prepare previews. Everytime a preview is ready, UI thread receives a signal (Handler is onUpdateIcon) to replace dummy icon.

```
void FlatFSItem::onUpdateIcon(QListWidgetItem *item, QPixmap pixmap) {
    FlatFSPage *page=qobject_cast<FlatFSPage *>(listWidget()->itemWidget(this));
    QListWidget *list=page->m_list;

    bool isItemValid=false;

    for(int i=0;i<list->count();i++) {
        if(list->item(i)==item) {
            isItemValid=true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!isItemValid)
        return;

    item->setIcon(QIcon(pixmap));
}
```

While appending a item with dummy icon, the file names are perfectly trimmed to fit the width of item. Redundant strings are replaced by "...". However, when the icon being updated, the file name are no longer trimmed and causes items cover each other.

Is it a bug? How to fix it?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's hard to tell, there could be a couple of reasons causing this - the new icon exceeding the 64x64 size you set on initialization, different format. There are a couple of approaches that could be attempted to solve this:

1) Delay adding the item to the widget until the image is actually loaded

2) Verify the size of the loaded image and resize to 64x64 if it exceeds it (btw, what size is `cloud.png` ?)

Comment: 1. I can't add the item until the image is actually loaded. Adding with dummy icon first, updating later is requirement.

2. cloud.png is 128 by 128.

3. I tried QListWidgetItem::setSizeHint() with the same size as grid...The problem seems like disappeared...But I don't know how...

Comment: Hmm, so that means if the grid size is 100 by 100 and icon 64 by 64 then the cloud png was actually being downscaled if it did not exceed the borders right?

Comment: Well, your code that updates the image after it has been loaded does not contain a `setSizeHint()` call, try to do that there too, maybe that is what triggers the downscaling.